# The search box sure needs some improvement

Tags: discussion

On trying to find some code that contains a (with the quotes included) `"}"` I did a search for `code:"}"` but that just search for a simple `}` as it takes the double quotes as some quoting mechanism (for which I can not find the description/rules/Howto).

Then I tried `code:'"}"'` for which I get backa page that states that the search term was:

```
Search options: code '"}"', not deleted
```

With no results. Then I though: Could it be outside of code sections?

So, I searched for `'"}"'`. And the reply was that

```
We couldn't find anything for '' "}"
```

I though: Why are the single quotes outside the quoted string? So, I tried: `/Hello"}"World/`

The reply was a list of some `Hello World` answers (yes, with the space). And the search reply had this: `Results for /helloworld/ "}"` at the start.

I though: Could it be better to quote the search? So I tried `"/Hello"}"World/" but the reply said:

```
Results for "/Hello" "World/"
```

The `}` got erased.

So: How could I search for the literal string `"}"` (with the quotes, yes) ?

Comment: There isn’t much documentation about code search on SE; for more general context, see [Can I search for a quoted word?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247202/285232)

Comment: More wood to the same fire: The search box needs help. @StephenKitt

Comment: Is the Search box a Unix & Linux thing, or a StackExchange thing?  If the latter, this particular Meta might not be an effective channel to request change.

Comment: @SottoVoce In the web page, the search box. The one up above the whole page. What would be an effective channel to request change, then ?

Comment: @QuartzCristal I've only been on the StackExchange sites since June, so I'm not an expert.  I merely noticed that the search box you're talking about is in the top bar (black color) with the StackExchange icon next to it, rather than in the part of the page labeled Unix&Linux.  After a bit of poking around the SE site, I found https://meta.stackexchange.com/ which might be the right place (or might not).  I recall an answer in this U&L Meta that pointed to an area where new features by the SE developers were announced.  Perhaps that can lead to the best place for your question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know, but I have some pointers to more information that was a bit too much for a comment:

- terdon mentioned an external search engine [in /dev/chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57386299#57386299) called http://www.symbolhound.com/; I've never used it, but it might be worth a try.
- There's [Quotes break the search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279945/quotes-break-the-search) that is from 2016 which is marked as fixed, but has several linked threads that talk about quoted searches.
- The most recent discussion seems to be on Meta SO: [Search for special characters isn't working as advertised](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368516/search-for-special-characters-isnt-working-as-advertised) where Shog9 says *"apparently this is something we broke in one of the Elastic upgrades, so it'll probably take some work to get it back"*

I believe that search is a core feature of the Stack Exchange software (nothing specific to U&L), so you may get better (more current, more informed) responses on Meta Stack Exchange.